# Asynchronous list of http PostAsync tasks causes internal server errror

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

I have a xamarin.forms app and there a ViewModel is supposed to make several post/put requests to web api. I thought I would do in asynchronously, first create a list of PostAsync/PutAsync tasks and then await all with `Task.WhenAll`.

All seems to be working fine, although at times (sometimes very often) I'm getting response code 500 internal server error. As this is quite general error description and I can't request against local server (can't run emulator), it's hard to trace what's wrong. I think it is related to the fact I'm doing it all asynchronously, because I have a lot of other requests in the app (each one awaited) and never got that error.

Here's the code in my ViewModel:

```
public async Task<string> Save(int handlingId, int processId)
{
        List<Task<string>> listOfTask = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach(ProcessAction pa in CheckedItems.Where(p=>(bool)p.IsMutable))
        {
            pa.HandlingId = handlingId;
            pa.ProcessId = processId;

            if ((bool)pa.IsMutable && (bool)pa.IsChecked)
            {
                if (pa.ProcessActionId == 0)
                {
                    listOfTask.Add(pa.Add());
                }
                else
                {
                    listOfTask.Add(pa.Edit());
                }
            }    
        }

        IEnumerable<string> results = await Task.WhenAll<string>(listOfTask);

        if(results.Where(r => r != "OK").Any())
        {
            return string.Join("; ", results.Where(r => r != "OK"));
        }
        else
        {
            return "OK";
        }
}
```

Here's `ProcessAction` that derives from Entity class and has Add() and Edit() methods contain generic T:

```
public virtual async Task<string> Add()
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string _Result = "OK";
            string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Create{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&UserId=" + RuntimeSettings.UserId;

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20), EnableUntrustedCertificates = true, DisableCaching = true });
                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await Static.Functions.GetPostRetryAsync(() => httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    _Result = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                }
                else
                {
                    var rString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    AddedItem = rString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Result = ex.Message;
                Static.Functions.CreateError(ex, "No connection", nameof(this.Add), this.GetType().Name);
            }

            return _Result;
        }
}

public async Task<string> Edit()
{
        string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Edit{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + $"&id={this.Id}&UserId={RuntimeSettings.CurrentUser.UserId}";
        string _Result = "OK";

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20), EnableUntrustedCertificates = true, DisableCaching = true });
            var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
            var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage result = await Static.Functions.GetPostRetryAsync(() => httpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(url), content), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _Result = result.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _Result = ex.Message;
            Static.Functions.CreateError(ex, "No connection", nameof(this.Edit), this.GetType().Name);
        }

        return _Result;
}
```

The PostAsync/PutAsync method itself is wrapped in GetPostRetryAsync method, which retries the request if network is broken. I'm posting it although I think no problem there:

```
  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPostRetryAsync(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action, TimeSpan sleepPeriod, int tryCount = 3)
  {
        int attempted = 0;
        bool pingable = false;
        CancellationTokenSource PingCts;
        CancellationTokenSource actionCts;
        HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage();
        Exception exc;

        if (tryCount <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(tryCount));

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                attempted++;

                if (attempted > 1)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IToaster>().LongAlert($"Próba {attempted}");
                }

                if (RuntimeSettings.IsVpnConnection || Secrets.ApiAddress==Secrets.WebioApiAddress)
                {
                    tryCount = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    WiFiInfo w = await DependencyService.Get<IWifiHandler>().ConnectPreferredWifi();
                    var formattedSsid = $"\"{Static.Secrets.PreferredWifi}\"";

                    if (w.SSID == formattedSsid)
                    {
                        tryCount = 1;
                    }
                }

                PingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var ping = Task.Run(() => DependencyService.Get<IWifiHandler>().PingHost(),PingCts.Token);
                actionCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var resTask = Task.Run(() => action(),actionCts.Token);

                Task firstFinieshed = await Task.WhenAny(ping, resTask);

                if (ping.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    pingable = await ping;
                    if (!pingable)
                    {
                        actionCts.Cancel();
                        exc = new ServerUnreachableException();
                        throw exc;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res = await resTask;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PingCts.Cancel();
                    res = await resTask;
                }

                return res ; // success!
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                --tryCount;
                if (tryCount <= 0)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                await Task.Delay(sleepPeriod);
            }
        }
}
```

And here are web api methods. They are *not* in async controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("EditProcessAction")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult EditProcessAction(string token, int id, int UserId, JDE_ProcessActions item)
{
        if (token != null && token.Length > 0)
        {
            var tenants = db.JDE_Tenants.Where(t => t.TenantToken == token.Trim());
            if (tenants.Any())
            {
                var items = db.JDE_ProcessActions.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.TenantId == tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId && u.ProcessActionId == id);
                if (items.Any())
                {
                    string descr = "Edycja przypisania czynności do zgłoszenia";
                    item.LmOn = DateTime.Now;
                    item.LmBy = UserId;
                    JDE_Logs Log = new JDE_Logs { UserId = UserId, Description = descr, TenantId = tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, OldValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items.FirstOrDefault()), NewValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item) };
                    db.JDE_Logs.Add(Log);
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        if (!JDE_ProcessActionExists(id))
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateProcessAction")]
[ResponseType(typeof(JDE_ProcessActions))]
public IHttpActionResult CreateProcessAction(string token, JDE_ProcessActions item, int UserId)
{
        if (token != null && token.Length > 0)
        {
            var tenants = db.JDE_Tenants.Where(t => t.TenantToken == token.Trim());
            if (tenants.Any())
            {
                item.TenantId = tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId;
                item.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                db.JDE_ProcessActions.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                JDE_Logs Log = new JDE_Logs { UserId = UserId, Description = "Utworzenie przypisania czynności do zgłoszenia", TenantId = tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, NewValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item) };
                db.JDE_Logs.Add(Log);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
}
```

I need a way to track this error. If I can enable detailed error descriptions being sent in response, that could be it. Maybe you can already tell that the way I'm querying server (multiple requests modifying SQL Server db via EF) is the reason? If that's the case, how can I do it properly without awaiting each request?

Comment: the first thing you need to do is figure out why you're getting a 500.  If you're not able to debug the server code, then you need to look at the server logs and possibly add some additional exception handling and logging to your server code.

Comment: Good pointer. I checked logs and there are EditProcessAction requests that resulted in error 500. How can I add more information to these logs?

Comment: google "webapi logging"

Comment: Thanks, it put me in the right direction. I set error locking on the API and found out that the error is caused by DateTime field containing some weird value..